# Compute automorphism group of graph / check if two graphs are isometric (DAG)

Tags: graph, isomorphism

This has to be a well researched problem, but I am struggling researching it.

I started here, but I am looking for algorithms to study and implement.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem

For example, if I have two of these DAGs (Directe Acyclic Graphs), I want to mark/delete one of them because it is just a rotation/reflection of the first. Being in the same automorphism group means they can be rotated/reflected to have the exact same adjacency matrix right?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use nauty or saucy algorithm to compute this problem.

This links might be helpful to you. :)

```
Nauty:
http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/nauty/
http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/nauty/

Saucy:
http://vlsicad.eecs.umich.edu/BK/SAUCY/
```

There is also a list of ready made tools available (especially for command line in linux based OS), in the saucy page.